# Webpack relative url(../images/example.png) does not work for node_modules package

Tags: webpack

In my project am importing a third-party css file from a node_modules package:

```css
@import(~codedoc/src/css/style.css)
```

That imported css file has relative paths for images, like so:

```css
    background-image: url(../images/icon-info.png)
```

I am getting the following error when building:

```
Error: Can't resolve '../images/icon-info.png'
```

I am using the following module rules in my `webpack.config.js`:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ],
  },
```

How can I make sure the relative URLs from the third-party package are handled correctly? Why does webpack not resolve the path relative to the css file?

Comment: you may find some clues here: [SASS @import and maintaining URLs for images etc](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1015)

Comment: after some more thought, why bother importing the css from the node_modules into your own css?  why not just import the package's css directly into your app's javascript somewhere?

Comment: @SethLutske I tried `import codedoc/src/css/style.css` in my `index.js`, but that does not fix the issue.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I see the solution in the Sass link you posted. Plus, I'm not using Sass.